# Слишком много кода в VIPER?

Tags: android, android-sdk, mvp

Здравствуйте. Я просмотрел много репозиториев с исходным кодом приложений, построенных по VIPER и прочитал пару статей про VIPER. Решил использовать его в своем новом проекте. Проект я почти закончил, но как мне показалось, при постронии приложения по VIPER, увеличивается количество кода и довольно ощутимо. Приложение небольшое (всего три экрана и две модельки), но кода получилось многовато. Еще один минус - огроменные конструкторы классов, для передачи в них интеракторов, репозиториев и т. д. Из плюсов можно отметить довольно легкое написание unit-тестов. Сейчас я задумался, а стоит ли вообще использовать его в своих будущих проектах? Поэтому вопрос такой: кто использует VIPER в своих проектах? Если не VIPER, то что используете вы и почему? Возможно ли построить по методологии VIPER действительно большое приложение? Например, мой следующий проект - электронная библиотека с магазином и читалкой электронных книг EPUB.